# Is it possible to convert files using external EXE and get unsaved to disk output as file-like object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, stdout

I have multiple files: `file_0001`, `file_0002` ... `file_n` and so on...

It needs to be processed using external command line tool.
So, for each particular file it has to be execute command prompt line like this:

```
tool.exe file_0001 output_file_0001
```

As you can see, the `output_file_0001` is always saving to the hard drive. After that each time I have to read this `output_file_0001` from disk with python script.

The question is:

is it possible to run this command from python script and catch `output_file_0001` as file-like object directly without unnecessary saving it to disk?

Comment: Just a quick idea: Did you think about piping/passing the data to your Python script using stdout and stdin? This could be a way to 'send' and 'recieve' data between the two parts and cobble `tool.exe` with your Python script.

Comment: @albert Interesting... I need to google details. Never have heard anything about that. Thanks, Albert!

Comment: If you created/have source for `tool.exe`, you could have it write to `stdout` instead of to a file name. If that cannot be changed, a named pipe could be used, but not for the feint of heart.